How to change panning value returned by xrandr -q
I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 24.04 (20.04 -> 22.04 -> 24.04). Everything works fine except my display.
xrandr -q return a panning value 2 times larger than my display.
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 519mm x 324mm panning 3840x1200+0+0

Where can I change that value?
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --panning 1920x1200 is not persistent after a reboot.

I finally found a solution. It appear there is a bug with Nvidia driver creating a ghost monitor.
How do disable/get rid of PRIME (None-1-1) display?

I don't want any panning and solve it by setting the active screen by xrandr -s widthxheight but if you want some panning, and the command line you show works, you should be able to add it via a .desktop file in the directory .config/autostart. That way it will be activated each time you start the graphical desktop environment (useful until the bug is squashed).
